# Dockerfile to generate a unit test image AND a production image

Tags: dockerfile, docker

I use a single dockerfile to build and run the following images:

**Production application image:**

```
docker build -t myapplication.program -f src/MyApplication.Program/dockerfile  --target runner --build-arg version=1.0.19031.1 .

docker run --rm -it -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=local -p 5050:5050 myapplication.program:latest
```

**Unit test and code coverage image:**

```
docker build -t myapplication.tests -f src/MyApplication.Program/dockerfile --target tester .

docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/codecoveragereports:/app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports myapplication.tests:latest
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Define the base image with .NET Core SDK to enable restoring, building & publishing the code.
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS builder
# Set working directory in the container to /app. All further actions to affect this directory.
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj files from the source (period indicating the root solution directory) to our image (period indicating working directory).
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Program/MyApplication.Program.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Program/MyApplication.Program.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Interfaces/MyApplication.Interfaces.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Interfaces/MyApplication.Interfaces.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.SignalR/MyApplication.SignalR.csproj ./src/MyApplication.SignalR/MyApplication.SignalR.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Protocol/MyApplication.Protocol.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Protocol/MyApplication.Protocol.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Domain/MyApplication.Domain.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Domain/MyApplication.Domain.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Infrastructure/MyApplication.Infrastructure.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Infrastructure/MyApplication.Infrastructure.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Services/MyApplication.Services.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Services/MyApplication.Services.csproj
COPY ./src/MyApplication.Actors/MyApplication.Actors.csproj ./src/MyApplication.Actors/MyApplication.Actors.csproj
# Copy nuget.config to root working directory - dotnet restore will use this.
COPY nuget.config ./
# Set working directory to starting project folder.
WORKDIR ./src/MyApplication.Program/
# Run dotnet package restore on all projects.
RUN dotnet restore
# Reset working directory back to /app
WORKDIR /app
# Copy all source code to image.
COPY ./src ./src
# Set working directory to starting project folder.
WORKDIR ./src/MyApplication.Program/
# Build the main project
RUN dotnet build MyApplication.Program.csproj -c Release

FROM builder as tester
# Set working directory in the container to /app. All further actions to affect this directory.
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj files from the source (period indicating the root solution directory) to our image (period indicating working directory).
COPY ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/MyApplication.UnitTests.csproj ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/MyApplication.UnitTests.csproj
# Set working directory to starting project folder.
WORKDIR ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/
# Run dotnet package restore on all projects.
RUN dotnet restore
# Reset working directory back to /app
WORKDIR /app
# Copy all source code to image.
COPY ./test ./test
# Set working directory to starting project folder.
WORKDIR ./test/MyApplication.UnitTests/
# Build the main project
RUN dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura
# Entry point command to generate the reports
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "reportgenerator", "-reports:coverage.cobertura.xml", "-targetdir:codecoveragereports", "-reportTypes:htmlInline"]

FROM builder as publisher
# Reset working directory back to /app
WORKDIR /app
# Set working directory to starting project folder.
WORKDIR ./src/MyApplication.Program/
# Expect an argument for the artefact version number.
ARG version
# Dotnet publish project.
RUN dotnet publish MyApplication.Program.csproj -c Release -o publish /p:Version=$version

# Define the base image with just the (lightweight) .NET Core runtime to host and run MyApplication.
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS runner
# Set working directory in the container to /app. All further actions to affect this directory.
WORKDIR /app
# Copy published output from the builder image.
COPY --from=publisher /app/src/MyApplication.Program/publish/ .
# Listen on this port at runtime.
EXPOSE 5050
# Set application entry point
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.Program.dll"]
```

Please code review my dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a few years since you asked this question.
I'm honestly not sure how much of the docker suggestions I make will have been relevant when you asked your question and I expect the application you are building to have evolved since then, but here's some suggestions nonetheless:

### Comment style

You are commenting basically every step of the process.
This is probably overkill.
Most of these comments are also obviously not useful for readers, since they just reformulate *what* the code does instead of giving context for why it is the way it is.
Basically ALL comments that are not on `FROM` statements are affected by this.

You can safely drop most of these comments in favor of explaining why you're doing things the way you are.
I would suggest explicitly clearing up that the long string of `COPY` commands for the restore is a caching optimization that speeds up builds when no `restore` is going to be required.
All the other comments seem to add little value for me.

### `dotnet` can traverse directories

You're making use of `WORKDIR` to do the job of directory traversal for dotnet.
That is unnecessary, since all dotnet commands have a way to alter their working directory automatically.

```
COPY nuget.config ./

RUN dotnet restore src/MyApplication.Program
COPY src src
RUN dotnet build src/MyApplication.Program/MyApplication.Program.csproj -c Release
```

### docker is not a scripting language

I dislike that your `tester` frontloads its testing steps into the docker build process.
Actually, thinking about it, I dislike that your docker build does all that `RUN dotnet` stuff.
As it is you're abusing the dockerfile to be a scripting language.

Really, what you are doing here is just formalizing your build steps into a dockerfile.
There is some good reasons to do that, but I would suggest that this is not what docker should be used for.

What you have here instead is a CI definition in disguise.
You have four stages: `build`, `test`, `publish` and `deploy`.
Each of these steps does not necessarily need to run on a developer machine if you want to release your application.
In fact I posit that it ***shouldn't***.

Your testing image is a glorified archive for coverage reports generated at docker build time.
That's not really a useful image.
Use a CI tool for your CI needs and use docker to supplement that CI tool with reproducible, software-defined environments.

Comment: Even for commands that do need a specific working directory, `WORKDIR` is usually the wrong approach, compared to `cd $dir &&` at the start of the `RUN` command.  BTW, fully agree that abusing Docker for its shell is weird and inefficient.